# Horizontal menu CSS not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a horizontal drop down menu with 3 levels of sub menus. I have almost created all menu items. I am trying to make it cross browser compatible. While I was testing in IE7 menu is not diaplaying properly. float is not working.  Please suggest me what to do?

here is my code:

```
<ul id="menu_new">
    <li><a href="#" class="HeaderLink">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="HeaderLink">Applications</a>
        <ul>                                      
            <li><a href="#">Agency</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/apps/banner/web_links/NVE_South_Agency_PRDv2.ica" >NVE South</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NVE North</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Manual Crawl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Crawl Interval</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Visual Analytics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
        <ul>                                      
            <li><a href="#">Manage Subject</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" >Add Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Delete Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export Subject</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Manual Crawl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Crawl Interval</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/16/)

Result in IE8:
[image: IE8]
Result in IE7:
[image: IE7]

Comment: Please stop support IE7..

Comment: We need to see the CSS but it could be an `inline-block` issue. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block) Then again **IE7!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menu_new > li{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
line-height:35px;
height:35px;
*display:inline;/*Add this code of line*/
zoom:1; /*and Add this code of line*/
}
```